# Select drop-down value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find below code, I have to get drop down selected value dynamically but I am not getting it.

```
<div class='box' id='dispositions'>
    <div class='header'>Dispositions</div>
    <form>
        <select name='rebuttal'>
            <option value=''>---Rebuttals Count---</option>
                <option value='0'>0</option>
                <option value='2-3'>2-3</option>
                <option value='3 or greater'>3 or greater</option>
        </select>
    </form>    
</div>
```

To achieve this I am using below code but its not giving expected result.

***No alert getting for below:-***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cc-panel-Disposition form [name=rebuttal]').change(function() {
    alert($("#cc-panel-Disposition form [name=rebuttal] option:selected").text());
  });  
});
```

In this below code I am getting 'rebVal' instead of the selected value. Please help me here.

```
var rebVal = $('#cc-panel-Disposition [name=rebuttal]').find('option:selected').val();
//var test = $('#cc-panel-Disposition form [name=rebuttal] option:selected').val();
                formValues.rebVal = rebVal;//rebVal;
```

Please let me know If I need to provide more information.

Comment: The values & texts are same. You can use value only.

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistake in selector, first of all you do not have id `cc-panel-Disposition` rather you have `dispositions` Secondly using this instead of using the same selector again in the event handler.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vyo2b95f/1/)**

```
$('#dispositions form [name=rebuttal]').change(function() {  
     alert($(this).find(':selected').text());
});
```

You can use name selector to bind the event, if you do not expect other control with same name

```
$('[name=rebuttal]').change(function() { ....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adil, it works. Can I store this selected value in a variable as I am trying in my asked question ?

Comment: Yes, var sel = this.value; as you have same text and value you can use this.value could be used instead of $(this).find(':selected').text()

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/0p69tjy2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#optionSelected').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
      });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to get elements from ids.

```
<div class='box' id='dispositions'>
    <div class='header'>Dispositions</div>
    <form>
        <select id='rebuttal'>
            <option value=''>---Rebuttals Count---</option>
                <option value='0'>0</option>
                <option value='2-3'>2-3</option>
                <option value='3 or greater'>3 or greater</option>
        </select>
    </form>    
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rebuttal').change(function() {
    alert($("#rebuttal option:selected").text());
  });  
});
```